# Resampling with Repa and Stencils

Tags: haskell, image-processing, resampling, repa, stencils

I wrote a simple image bilinear resampling algorithm with repa and since I need to use partitioned arrays to make it correct, I thought I would go whole hog and use stencils too and hopefully get faster loops.

From my naive understanding of the way mapStencil works, I don't think it is sufficient for my task. I need something like transformStencil. I guess I would need a different Stencil to, so I could have the old index and the new one.

Is there an simple way to perform stenciled image resampling in Repa? If not, how hard would it be hack up mapStencil into transformStencil or something equivalent.

Comment: Could you write a signature of `transformStencil`, it's hard to understand what did you want to obtain.